# django "No migrations to apply" after merged from git repository

Tags: django, django-migrations

My partner did some changes in a model of our app. He ran *makemigrations* and *migrate*, everything success until now. The migrations files were created and pushed to our git repository.

At this point the migrations folder is:

- 0001_initial.py
- 0002_field1.py

After that I did a merge and I got the new migrations files. Before that I just had 0001_initial.py. Now I got both.

Problem is when I run migrate I got that "No migrations to apply". Why not?? if field1 is not yet in my database, but in models does, and I have the latest migrations files, which are not sync with database yet.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment due my low score, but, you can try to run `$ ./manage.py showmigrations` to check if your migration is detected by Django and if it's not already done

Answer (score 1):

Did you destroy all the migrations at some point prior to this? I think if you use the --fake-initial it should help.